# Find the extremal of $\int_a^b (y'^2+2yy'-16y^2)\, dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The task is to find the extremals of:
$$\int_a^b (y^{\prime2}+2yy^\prime-16y^2)\, dx$$ 
I used the Euler-Lagrange equation and I got:
$$-2y^{\prime\prime} - 32y = 0$$
I solved the differential equation
$$y = c_2 \sin(4x) + c_1 \cos(4x)$$

But according to my textbook the solution should be $y = c_1\sin(4x-c_2)$. Can anyone explain please, where my mistake is?

Thanks.

Comment: First rule of calculus involving trigonometry: if you can't see why you're wrong, the answers probably agree by an identity you didn't know or notice. Don't worry, this comes up here all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand the textbook solution to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
y & = c_1\sin(4x - c_2) \\
& = c_1(\sin(4x)\cos(c_2) - \cos(4x)\sin(c2)) \\
& = (c_1\cos(c_2))\sin(4x) + (-c_1\sin(c2))\cos(4x)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note you can choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ values to allow any set of $2$ coefficients for the $\sin(4x)$ and $\cos(4x)$ terms, so this is basically equivalent to your solution.

To see why you have the full range of possible values, the second coefficient divided by the first gives

$$\frac{-c_1\sin(c2)}{c_1\cos(c2)} = -\tan(c_2) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since the range of $\tan()$ is all real numbers, this means you can use the corresponding ratio of your two coefficients (call them $c_2'$ and $c_1'$ to help avoid confusion) to get

$$\frac{c_2'}{c_1'} = -\tan(c_2) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This determines a value of $c_2$ in the range of $0$ to $2\pi$, and with this, if $\cos(c_2) \neq 0$, you can then get $c_1$ from

$$c_1 = \frac{c_2'}{\cos(c_2)} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

else, you can get it instead from

$$c_1 = \frac{-c_1'}{\sin(c_2)} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

I'm leaving out certain details such as with $\cos(c_2) = 0$, i.e., the $\cos(4x)$ term having a coefficient of $0$, but these don't affect the generality of the textbook answer compared to yours.

For a more graphical/visual way to see this, consider the equation of a circle of radius $|c_1|$ centered at the origin is

$$x^2 + y^2 = c_1^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

You have that $(c_1\cos(c_2), -c_1\sin(c_2))$, as $c_2$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, are the set of all of the points on this circle. As $|c_1|$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, the set of points on the circle sweeps the entire plane, i.e., all points.

Answer (score 0):

F= y'²+2yy'-16y²

F doesn't depend explicitly on x .

The Euler equation is ,

F-y'Fy' = c1

Fy'= 2y'+2y

y'Fy' = 2y'²+2yy'

F-y'Fy'= y'²+2yy'-16y²-2y'²-2yy'= c1

y'²+16y²=c1

y'² = c1-16y²

y'²=16(c2-y²)

y'= 4√(c2-y²)

dy/√(c2-y²) =4dx

Integrate

Sin inverse of (y/c2) = 4x+c3

y/c2 = sin (4x+c3)

y= c2sin(4x+c3)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).